# How do I make a URL text a link?

Tags: php

Say on Facebook or Twitter, when I type "www.google.com" and submit it, it becomes a link. How do I code this in PHP? Do I use regular expressions to get where the www starts and the .com ends?

Is this how they do it?

```
<?PHP 
//some regular expression to get www and .com part
$link="<a href='$url'>$url</a>";
echo $link;
?>
```

How do I write a regular expression to get the "www" and ".com" part?

And for twitter's @obama, obama would become a link to obama's site.
What regular expression do they use to get the text after the @ and before the space?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<?php

$str = "Lorem http://myyn.org dolor sit amet, http://google.com adipisicing ..";

$str = preg_replace("#(^|[\n ])([\w]+?://[\w\#$%&~/.\-;:=,?@\[\]+]*)#is",
                    "\\1<a href=\"\\2\">\\2</a>", 
                    $str); 

echo $str . "\n";

?>
```

Example:

```
$ php 2935574.php 
Lorem <a href="http://myyn.org">http://myyn.org</a> dolor sit amet, \
<a href="http://google.com">http://google.com</a> adipisicing elit.
```

Comment: thank you. I'm new to regular expressions so it'll take some time to digest this.

Answer (score 3):

And for Twitter you could use something like this.

```
$str = "@obama This is a test";
$str = preg_replace('/@([\w-]+)/', '@<a href="http://twitter.com/\\1">\\1</a>', $str);
echo $str; // @<a href="http://twitter.com/obama">obama</a> this is a test
```

Comment: thank you! works perfectly. Now I'm trying to understand it. What exactly is the \1 and \2?

Comment: The text matched between the brackets "`(` and `)`" can be referenced back by using \\\[number], the first brackets will be in \\1, the second on \\2 and so on. See also http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html.

A good read on my word character shorthand (`\w`) can be found at http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html.

Comment: ahh I see, that got me. i'll look into the books.